# Dataset is not retrieving results in SSRS designer

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2017

I am trying to execute oracle stored procedure with input parameters as startdate and enddate. When i tried to add dataset with Oracle stored procedure.

```
    create or replace PROCEDURE  Getsummary_data(i_start_date                 IN   DATE
                                                      ,i_end_date                   IN   DATE
                                                      ,o_summary_data      OUT  SYS_REFCURSOR)
is
BEGIN
   IF    i_start_date IS NOT NULL
   AND   i_end_date   IS NOT NULL
.....
```

When I created Dataset with the above stored procedure,it is not showing  result data in report data pane for dataset.

[image]

Please let me know what could be reason why I am not able to see result data in Report Data.
When I tried execute dataset with parameters(startdate and enddate),I am able to see resultset.
Is it like stored procedure should accept null input parameters

Comment: There might be a problem in a procedure. You could first test if it works. Call the procedure in Oracle SQL Developer, or whatever IDE you are using and see if there are errors.

Comment: Everthing is working fine in Oracle sql developer.Even in SSRS designer the procedure is giving results if i provide start date and endate.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you mentioned there are results when you choose dates. What about conditions `IF i_start_date IS NOT NULL AND i_end_date IS NOT NULL`? What happens when these conditions are not met? *Is it like stored procedure should accept null input parameters* - Yes, in that case you would show all results, in spite of date.

Comment: I changed the parameters to accept null in stored procedure and its working fine.